# OData Custom Action Response Restrictions

Tags: json, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

We have to talk to a Microsoft Dynamics 365 Api. When calling an custom action we retrieve a json as in the example below

```
{
    "@odata.context": "just-a-domain",
    "ids": "[{\"account\":\"whatever_id\",\"name\":\"test 2\"}]"
}
```

As you see the value of `ids` comes as string, but it should be json. Is there any restrictions for the return values in Dynamics 365?

The expected output should be like

```
{
    "@odata.context": "just-a-domain",
    "ids": [
        {
             "account": "whatever_id",
             "name": "test 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Didn't find anything about it in the documentation. But the guy who's implementing the custom actions claims it is not possible to do it in any other way.

Comment: Is this an output parameter from custom action or something else?

Comment: I've tried it with `...?$format=json`. That request has an Accept header with `application/json` anyway. Makes no difference.

Comment: Share the complete code, action screenshot, etc to understand better..

Comment: What you see in that grey box is the response body of a request i've made in Postman. I request a custom action in a Dynamics365-Api. What other information should i provide?

Comment: @ArunVinoth please don't get me wrong. I'm on the consumer side of that api. 
The question is: Can somebody confirm that the values of the root keys in a json-response of the Dynamics365-Api custom-action have to be a string? This is what i got told by the one who's implementing the custom action. I don't believe it.

Comment: Can you show the expected behavior what you want in question itself, edit & add it

Comment: updated it to show the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the data types supported in Custom action output parameter:

> [image]

That being said, JSON is not the straight supported Output param type, but you can ask your CRM developer to give you back some fixed format anyway.

Simply serialized JSON in `String` Output type, `EntityCollection` Or `Entity` types may help you if I understand your need correctly. [Read more](https://debajmecrm.com/2018/05/28/quick-tip-pass-a-custom-single-collection-of-objects-with-custom-properties-as-output-parameter-from-actions-in-dynamics-365/)